# Azure App Service: WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE - does old zip files gets deleted?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

When I use Azure DevOps to deploy a zip file to d:\home\data\SitePackages it also sets the name of the file in packagename.txt and set WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE to 1, but what about deleting old zip files? Does Azure or DevOps handle that? Or do I need to do it myself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Azure App Service: WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE - does old zip files gets deleted?

According to your description, it seems you want to empty the old zip files before a new deployment.

If it is, When using the **Azure App Service Deploy** task, **and** you are using the **Publish using Web Deploy** option, there is an additional option to **Remove Additional Files at Destination**.

[image]

If you check this option, the deployment process will remove any files at the destination where there is no corresponding file in the package that is being deployed.

In other words, it'll remove any left over files from a previous deployment that are no longer required.

Refer to [Removing Deleted Files during Visual Studio Team Services Azure App Service Deploy Task](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/crmchap/archive/2018/02/25/removing-deleted-files-during-visual-studio-team-services-azure-app-service-deploy-task) for details.

**Update:**

> But when running from package the zip files is located in another folder, and the wwwroot folder is mounted to this zip, as read-only, so there will only be the files that should be there in wwwroot. I am asking if the zip files gets deleted when deploying a new, and using WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE.

It seems you are using Run From Package to deploy a zip file, If yes, **azure devops will not delete the old zip file, we just need to update the text file that points at it, which allow us to easily switch back if we need to**. Check the document [Deploy Web and Function Apps with Run from Package](https://markheath.net/post/run-from-package) and [Run From Package: a new way to deploy your Azure Web Apps and Function Apps](https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements/issues/84) for some more details.

> What i am looking for is, if Kudu, DevOps or some other entity in
>   Azure, clean up the zip files in the deployment folder, or if the deployment folder just grows and grows.

You could try the extension [Azure WebApp Virtual File System](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=geertvdcruijsen.GeertvanderCruijsen-Vsts-Release-AzureWebAppVFS) Tasks, it can delete files from Azure Web Apps through KUDU Virtual File System Rest API (Put & Get coming soon). Check [this thread](https://blog.kloud.com.au/2016/08/30/interacting-with-azure-web-apps-virtual-file-system-using-powershell-and-the-kudu-api/) for some details.

Hope this helps.

Comment: But when running from package the zip files is located in another folder, and the wwwroot folder is mounted to this zip, as read-only, so there will only be the files that should be there in wwwroot. I am asking if the zip files gets deleted when deploying a new, and using WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE.

Comment: @mslot, Thanks for your reply. If you are using Run From Package to  deploy a zip file, it seems azure devops will not delete the old zip file, we just need to update the text file that points at it, which allow us to easily switch back if we need to. Check the document https://markheath.net/post/run-from-package and https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements/issues/84 for some more details.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements-discussions/issues/32. I have asked my question there. What i am looking for is, if Kudu, DevOps or some other entity in Azure, clean up the zip files in the deployment folder, or if the deployment folder just grows and grows.

Answer (score 1):

If you use ZipDeploy, it will keep 5 zip files by default. See https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Configurable-settings#zipdeploy-to-keep-at-most-last-n-zip-files

Comment: Where in the docs does it say that? I can't see it xD

Comment: was posting wrong link, updated, see SCM_MAX_ZIP_PACKAGE_COUNT